# Files and images not loading Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to load CSS and images for my spring MVC project and the CSS and Images are not kicking in. I've tried a lot of methods and even update my jars to 4.0.0.

**This is my servlet**

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"   >

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.pack.model, com.pack.controllers" />

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
      <property name = "username" value = "bafana"/>
      <property name = "password" value = "bafana"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for login dao bean -->
   <bean id = "loginDao" class = "com.database.accessobjects.LoginDao">
      <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource" />    
   </bean>

</beans>
```

**This is my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelpDesk</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelpDesk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my **loginModel.jsp** login file where the CSS and images should load

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <spring:url value="/resources/LoginStyle.css" var="KstyleCSS-login" />
        <spring:url value="/resources/zensar.png" var="zensar-logo-login" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="${KstyleCSS-login}" type="text/css" media="all"> 

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-div">
            <div class="logo"><img src="${zensar-logo-login}" alt="zensar.png"></img></div>
            <div class="header">
                <h2>Help-Desk Services</h2>
                <h5><strong>${msg}</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="logIn container">
                <form:form method = "POST" action = "/HelpDesk/logMeIn" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <form:input path = "username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username"  placeholder="Enter your username"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <form:input path = "password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Enter your Password"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <input name="mysubmit" id="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Login"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2017, Zensar Ltd. All Rights Reserved </p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have structured my folder like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to just use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/LoginStyle.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/LoginStyle.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```